How do I print out the value of a list instead of a memory location?
class Student:
    def __init__(self, name, year):
        self.name = name
        self.year = year
        self.grades = []
    
    def add_grade(self, grade):
       if type(grade) is Grade: 
           self.grades.append(grade)
        
roger = Student("Roger van der Weyden", 10) 
sandro = Student("Sandro Botticelli", 12)
pieter = Student("Pieter Bruegel the Elder", 8)        

class Grade:
    minimum_passing = 65
    
    def __init__(self, score):
        self.score = score
    
    def is_passing(self):
        if self.score >= self.minimum_passing:
            print("Cool")
        else:
            print("Kys")
              
pieter.add_grade(Grade(100))
pieter.add_grade(Grade(89))

pieter_result = Grade(55)
pieter_result.is_passing()
print(pieter.grades) #This is printing out the location address instead of the value


An example of the new code I tested
class Student:
    def __init__(self, name, year):
        self.name = name
        self.year = year
        self.grades = []
    
    def add_grade(self, grade):
        if isinstance(grade, Grade): 
            self.grades.append(grade)
           
roger = Student("Roger van der Weyden", 10) 
sandro = Student("Sandro Botticelli", 12)
pieter = Student("Pieter Bruegel the Elder", 8)        

class Grade:
    minimum_passing = 65
    
    def __init__(self, score):
        self.score = score
    
    def is_passing(self):
        if self.score >= self.minimum_passing:
            print("Passing")
        else:
            print("Failing")
    
    # def __str__(self):
    #   return str(self.grades)

    # def __repr__(self):
    #   return str(self.score)

#Both of these additions still provide the same output.
            
pieter.add_grade(Grade(100))
pieter.add_grade(Grade(89))

pieter_result = Grade(55)
pieter_result.is_passing()
print(pieter.grades)


I was doing an activity and I began thinking of ways to solve this problem that I'm having. A lot of resources have been telling me to create an __str__ or __repr__ method but it just doesn't work. I keep getting an output of [<__main__.Grade object at 0x00000241FC4774D0>, <__main__.Grade object at 0x00000241FC477510>] but what I need is values 100 and 89.
I'm still trying to wrap my head around the concept of constructors and calling them, but even with my understanding it's not making sense why the location is appearing. Adding values to the list manually seems to work, but I don't understand how the for loop isn't doing that already.

Tried print(*pieter.grades)?

Does this answer your question? Pythonic way to print list items

Putting a __repr__ on Grade does fix this.

The grades List is a list of Grade objects and you have not defined way of printing the score value within a Class instance. Hence the objects themselves are shown. So you need to define how to construct a string which is then used by print:
If you change the Grade class definition to include:
def __repr__(self):
    return f"{self.score}"

then the printed output will be as follows which I think is what you expect:
Kys
[100, 89]

